# How to set the permissions of my driver file using udev rules

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I am trying to set the permissions on my device driver file to read/write for all users using udev rules but it does work. 
here the udev rules :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="lpc*", KERNEL=="lpc?*", DRIVER=="lpc", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"
```

When I test it using :

```
sudo udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/lpc_peach)2>&1
```

this is what i get at the bottom lines :

```
preserve permissions /dev/lpc_peach, 020600, uid=0, gid=0
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/248:0' to '../lpc_peach'
```

I can't identify what is wrong! Any help will be useful.

**Edit 1** : When I run `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/lpc_peach` here is what I get:

```
P: /devices/virtual/lpc_spartan/lpc_peach
N: lpc_peach
E: DEVNAME=/dev/lpc_peach
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/lpc_spartan/lpc_peach
E: MAJOR=247
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=lpc_spartan
```

Comment: What does `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/lpc_peach` output? Also, did you either reboot or reload the rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload` after editing the rules?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how fussy it is about syntax, but you might need double quotes around `users`.

Comment: Oh my bad, you are right. There is indeed double quote around users . Yes I tried that but nothing happened. I also tried:    sudo service udev restart   , the same

Comment: The `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/lpc_peach` output doesn't contain `E: DRIVER=lpc`, so perhaps your udev rule shouldn't be trying to match on `DRIVER=="lpc"`.

Comment: I went off yesterday by the time you replied. I just removed that and it is now working like a charm. Thanks a lot for the help ^^